# how to access PDF/image/video file located in java server from a browser URL?

Tags: java, jsp, web.xml

I have an mp4 video on my GlassFish java application server. What URL do I use to access it in a browser?

The video path in the application on the server is:

```
myapp/WEB-INF/videos/myvideo.mp4
```

I tried adding this to my `web.xml` file:

```
<servlet>
  <servlet-name>myvideo</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>videos.myvideo.mp4</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>myvideo</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/myvideo</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

and restart the server, then go to the URL: `https://www.example.com/myapp/myvideo` but that just gave this error:

`java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: videos.myvideo.mp4`

Obviously it's not a servlet, but not sure what else to try.

Comment: Why are you trying to access the video as a servlet and not as a static asset, like you would an image? Using a servlet mapping is obviously wrong.

Comment: @radimpe, Because I don't know better. How to access as static asset? If I store the video in my public_html directory, I know how to access it. But, when it's located in my GlassFish application server's web container, I'm not sure.

Comment: If you have a running WebApp in GlassFish you should be able to access it via `https://www.example.com/myapp/videos/myvideo.mp4` assuming you've put the videos folder under your webapp's j2ee root.

Comment: Thanks @radimpe, I've placed the video here: `myapp/WEB-INF/videos/myvideo.mp4`. Is that the web app's j2ee root? I'm seeing a 404 error `The requested resource () is not available.` when visiting `https://www.example.com/myapp/videos/myvideo.mp4`

Comment: It depends on what you've configured in your application.xml as your `web-uri` but it is likely that the `myapp` folder is your j2ee root. So move your videos up a folder.

Comment: Thanks @radimpe, Moving it up one directory allowed the file to load. However, the browser didn't appear to recognize it as a video because the screen was full of stuff like this `�'62w= ��G\:���,@r��%`

Comment: Adding the following to my `web.xml` file caused the browser to identify the file as a video and play it:    `<mime-mapping>     <extension>mp4</extension>
     <mime-type>video/mp4</mime-type>
   </mime-mapping>`

Comment: I believe that would be a mime type issue (but that is a new question)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you trying to access the video as a servlet and not as a static asset, like you would an image? Using a servlet mapping is obviously wrong.

Instead if you have a running WebApp in GlassFish you should be able to access it via `https://www.example.com/myapp/videos/myvideo.mp4` assuming you've put the videos folder under your webapp's j2ee root.

The j2ee root would be configured in your application.xml as the `web-uri`. In your case it is likely that the `myapp` folder is your j2ee root. So move your videos up a folder.

(Converted comment 'discussion' into an answer).